# Expression Engine Forum Alternating Classes

Tags: module, forum

Reading the [expression engine forum display forum topics](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/forum/recent_forum_topics.html#auto-thread-path)
There is no count variable. I want to alternate classes for each result so it can have different background colors. There is no other property I can use that would also stand in for it for alternation. Anyone know what I can do for alternating classes for each forum topic result?

I don't know if anyone will see this, I miss the forums.

Comment: Have you tried the switch tag? It may work even though it is not in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

Use the `{switch}` tag. Separate switches by the `|` pipe character, they will cycle through.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="10" switch="green|blue|red"}
    <h2 class="{switch}">{title}</h2>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Will output

```
<h2 class="green">My title</h2>
<h2 class="blue">My title</h2>
<h2 class="red">My title</h2>
<h2 class="green">My title</h2>
<h2 class="blue">My title</h2>
<h2 class="red">My title</h2>
etc...
```

Comment: I believe the switch only works for entries loops not the exp:forum loops.

Answer (score 0):

You also can do this is pure CSS using the CSS3 nth-child pseudo selector.

```
#yourtableid tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #99ff99;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this should work without having to enabling php for the template (was my original solution)!